# Oracle Sql statement in java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Hey I am trying to run a java program in a Oracle sql load.sql file. Whilerunning the program I am getting the error "ORA-00904: "C"."STAFFID": invalid identifier". I think the issue is in where I prepare the sql statement and trying to execute it. I am trying to get information out from two sql tables: a2_loan and a2_customer. In a2_loan i want to get the loan_num and the contract_date, while in the table a2_customer I want the name and the ird_num.
My statement is currently:

```
String sql = "select a.name, ird_num, loan_num, contract_date from a2_loan, customer b, customer c where aname=b.ird_num and b name=c.name";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

I think it is in here that the problem lies but if it is somewhere else please tell me and I will copy the rest of my code!

Comment: You say the table name is `a2_customer` but in the SQL statement you are referring to just `customer`.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be a2_customer in your query?

Comment: correct your where clause. 
`where a.name=b.ird_num and b.name=c.name`

Comment: Your updated SQL doesn't have a table with alias `c` anymore, so any `c.` will fail. SQL doesn't have a `"C"."STAFFID"`, so your error cannot be for *this* SQL.

Comment: You keep editing the SQL query, and it doesn't add up to the question text. Last edit (#5) is not even valid syntax. I'd suggest you delete this question, figure out what it is you want to ask, then post a new question. **Closing as "unclear what you're asking".**

Comment: I've rolled back to an earlier version of the SQL and restored the latest error message reported by OP. I'm still not sure we can salvage this but at least now the error message and the SQL appear to be in sync.

Comment: run query once in db and check for result and errors before adding this in java..........

Answer (score 3):

*Note: This answer applied to original question.*

SQL statement with annotations:

```sql
select a.name           -- 'a' is undefined
     , ird_num          -- note: always qualify (helps others read it)
     , loan_num         --   same
     , contract_date    --   same
  from a2_loan          -- is this support to have alias 'a'?
     , customer b       -- not table `a2_customer`
     , customer c       -- not table `a2_customer`
 where aname=b.ird_num  -- missing period(?), and 'a' is undefined
   and b name=c.name    -- missing period
```