# Java Oracle Sql statement not performing

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Hey I am trying to run a java program in a Oracle sql load.sql file. Whilerunning the program I am getting the error "ORA-00920: invalid relational operator ". I think the issue is in where I prepare the sql statement and trying to execute it. I am trying to get information out from two sql tables: a2_loan and a2_customer. In a2_loan i want to get the loan_num and the contract_date, while in the table a2_customer I want the name and the ird_num. My statement is currently:

```
     String sql = "select a.name, ird_num, loan_num, contract_date from a2_loan a, a2_customer b where a.name=b.name and b.name";
```

I think it is in here that the problem lies but if it is somewhere else please tell me and I will copy the rest of my code!

I want to be getting the loan_num and contract_date out of the table a2_loan
And the name and ird_num out of the table a2_customer

Comment: "and b.name" what?  Does it equal something?

Comment: This seems to be the same question that you asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752298/oracle-sql-statement-in-java  At a minimum, your query appears to be cut off.  " and b.name" is not a valid way to end a query.  I'm guessing that you either want to remove that or you want to compare `b.name` to something.

Comment: Yes sorry I don't fully understand it yet. In order to get the information out of the table do I even need to compare b.name to anything at all? Or can I simply have "SELECT name, ird_num, loan_num, contract_date FROM a2_loan, a2_customer"    ?

Comment: Does `select a.name, ird_num, loan_num, contract_date from a2_loan a, a2_customer b where a.name=b.name` work?

Comment: Yes you need to compare it . Unless you compare some column the result will be that you will get each row in table A joined with each row in table B, you need to declare the condition so it will know which row in table A to connect to which row in table B

Comment: Is it possible for you to explain that through my example sagi?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest that you work on getting the SQL statement to work first outside of your Java application in SQL*Plus/ SQL Developer/ whatever front end GUI you have.  Then worry about getting it to work in Java.  Go one step at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Your query, slightly reformatted, is

```
select a.name, ird_num, loan_num, contract_date
  from a2_loan a,
       a2_customer b
  where a.name=b.name
    and b.name
```

The problem is in the last line. `and b.name` - what? `and b.name = something`? We can't tell from your query what you're trying to do, but in the last line you must compare `b.name` to something, or else you need to get rid of the entire last line.

Best of luck.